# "failed with exit code 2" while trying to install rebound with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I have just started to get into coding and wanted to install REBOUND via `pip` for Python. I tried using the terminal in VS code and the cmd one but same problem. I have installed VS builder tools 2022 but the problem persists. I have been able to clone the repository for it to work in C but I want it to be able to work in python as I am trying to learn Python.

```
Collecting rebound
  Using cached rebound-3.23.5.tar.gz (295 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: rebound
  Building wheel for rebound (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for rebound (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\citations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\horizons.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\interruptible_pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\particle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\plotting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\simulation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\simulationarchive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\units.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\widget.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      copying rebound\rebound.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\rebound
      running build_ext
      building 'librebound' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -IC:\Users\Gurar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Gurar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/binarydiff.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/binarydiff.obj -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=451e1cfb48231782c119bca5c69b42e617af1b13 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
      cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unknown-pragmas'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rebound
Failed to build rebound
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rebound, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This is all the output I got which personally I am unable to understand. Other Python packages are installing just fine. I have the 2022 vs code and Python 3.11.

Tried installing 2022 VS builder tools, it didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/hannorein/rebound/issues/604 says you have to use WSL; apparently native Windows isn't really supported.

Comment: But the site has instructions to install it on windows, no? I suppose it should work on windows too.

Comment: If the author says in a bug report it's not supported, I don't see why you suppose that.

Answer (score 0):

Running `pip install rebound` builds REBOUND's C extensions from source as an install step. Since you're running Windows, it uses the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (MSVC) to build the C source.

The relevant error message in the build is:

```
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unknown-pragmas'
```

MSVC doesn't support this compiler option (other C compilers like gcc do), so the build fails.

Based on this, it looks like REBOUND doesn't support Windows directly.

[Their quickstart documentation](https://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart_installation/) confirms this under the "Installing REBOUND on Windows" section. To install REBOUND on Windows, you must install it using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).